# How to install Java in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, java, 20.04

How do I install Java for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: What version would you like to install?

Comment: I'd like to install Java SE 14

Answer (score 2):

As taken from [this list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jdk), you'll likely want to run:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk
```

This will install the Java 14 JDK which will allow you to run Java programs and develop in Java.  Remember that JDK 14 is not a "LTS" release - it will no longer be supported in September of 2020 (see [the Oracle release roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html) for details).